# Can cells be merged without adding a blank line

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

If I merge multiple cells in a Jupyter notebook, there is a blank line between the code from each cell.

[image]

Can I merge cells without this blank line?

Answer (score 0):

- No, this is the expected behavior.
- Here is the [source](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/master/packages/notebook/src/actions.tsx#L164) for `mergeCells`
- Here is the [line](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/master/packages/notebook/src/actions.tsx#L226) that joins the contents `toMerge`

  - `newModel.value.text = toMerge.join('\n\n');`

    - `const toMerge: string[] = [];`
  - Note, there are 2 new lines, `'\n'` in the `.join()`, therefore the answer to *Can I merge cells without this blank line?* is **no**, unless you do a PR for the project, change the desired line, compile and run it on your system.